# Extract gateway address for given route in Server 2008 Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2008

Situation I've got is needing to deploy a new network route to a few thousand servers in multiple environments with different network routes etc. I'd like to write a script that fires by GPO which grabs the gateway address used for a currently configured route, then uses that gateway address to create a new route for the additional subnet I need to add.

A bit of research found this solution for Server 2012 which is easy enough:

```
get-netroute -DestinationPrefix "192.168.0.1/24" | select-object -expandproperty "NextHop"
```

This then provides me just the gateway address used for the network route '192.168.0.1/24'. I can then feed that into a variable to create a new route.

On Server 2008 R2 and below this command isn't available though, so I'm wondering if there's another clever way I could complete this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following. Tested on Server 2008 R2. This only extracts the default gateway but you mentioned you can use that to create the new route. Please test on different OS localizations if applicable before relying on it.

```
$defaultgw = (((route print 0.0.0.0 | ? {$_ -Match '0\.0\.0\.0.*[a-z]'}) -Replace '0\.0\.0\.0|[a-z]|\s+','') -Split '`r`n')[0]
$defaultgw
```

What this does is that it takes the output of `route print 0.0.0.0`, looks for characters `[a-z]` in each string (note that this is case insensitive by default in PowerShell) signifying that it is the `Default` route and removes this text, `0.0.0.0` and whitespaces from the string. What remains should be the default gateway.

Answer (score -1):

Nick,

Per [Microsoft site](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826123.aspx), Get-Netroute cmdlet is available on Powershell 5.0.

Comment: That same page (under "Other versions") only list versions from Win8/2012 and up

Comment: I've already found that solution for 2012 as I mentioned - but I need to find a way to get the same information on Server 2008R2 and below.